# Handling the cleanup of the gen_server state

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a `gen_server` running which it must clean up its state whenever it is stopped normally or it crash unexpectedly. The cleanup basically consists in deleting a few files.

At this moment, when the `gen_server` crash or it is stopped normally, the cleanup is done in `terminate/2`.

Is there any reason why `terminate/2` would not be called if the `gen_server` crash?

Should be any other process monitoring the `gen_server` waiting to do the cleanup if the `gen_server` dies unexpectedly?

So, the code is like this:

```
terminate(normal, State) ->
    % Invoked when the process stops
    % Clean up the mess
terminate(Error, State) ->
    % Invoked when the process crashes
    % Clean up the mess
```

---

EDIT: I found this email in the official mailing list which is talking about the same thing:

http://groups.google.com/group/erlang-programming/browse_thread/thread/9a1ba2d974775ce8

As Adam says below, if we want to avoid to trap the exists in the `gen_server`, we could use different approaches.

But if we trap the exists, `terminate/2` seems to be a safe place to do the cleanup as it always will be called. Furthermore we must handle correctly when `'EXIT'` is sent to `terminate/2` and to `handle_call/3` trying to propagate the errors correctly between workers and supervisors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`terminate/2` is called when a crash occur inside the `gen_server` even if it doesn't trap exits, it will not be called if it receives an 'EXIT' from some other process linked to it, in case you need to clean up then it should trap exits(using `process_flag(trap_exit, true)`).

This behavior is a bit unfortunate because it makes it difficult to write a reliable shutdown procedure for a `gen_server` process. Also, it is not a good habit to trap exits just for the sake of being able to run `terminate/2`, since you might catch a lot of other errors which makes it harder to debug the system.

I would consider three options:

1. Handle the left over files when the next instance of the process starts (for example, in `init/1`)
2. Trap exits, clean up the files, and then crash again with the same reason
3. Have a 3rd process which monitors the `gen_server` whose only purpose is to clean up the files

Option 1 is probably the best option, since at least the code doesn't trap exits and you get persistent state for free. Option 2 is not so nice for the reasons described above, that it can hide and obscure other errors. 3 is messy because the cleanup process might not be done before the `gen_server` is started again.

Think carefully about why you want to clean up, and if it really has to be done when the process crashes (it is a bug, after all). Be careful that you don't end up doing too much defensive programming.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK `terminate/2` will be called even when the `gen_server` doesn't trap exits. Trapping them is needed to handle when your parent crashes.

Comment: I ran some tests and `terminate/2` is invoked when the `gen_server` crashes, so under what circumstances is possible that `terminate/2` is not called?

Comment: When you get an exit signal from another process.

Comment: I think the discussion here under shows that it needs to be a community wiki. Unfortunately the OTP behaviors are a bit tricky and obscure when it comes to these kind of things. Please edit the post if you find that something is wrong or missing!

Comment: @Ricardo: Strictly, `terminate/2` is not called when your parent crashes (it's impossible without trapping exits). The exception might be supervisors, which trap exists and could terminate their children gracefully (I'm not sure if they do that). `terminate/2` called when the `gen_server` itself crashes, though, because it is possible to catch an exit generated in the same process without using `trap_exit`.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite fresh and relevant
[When does terminate/2 get called in a gen_server?](https://gist.github.com/mrallen1/806fe5506132260574af33e99dadd499)